# PHP session not persistent with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, session, authentication

I'm working on making a website (developing locally) that requires a login for users; I've used [php-login.net framework](http://www.php-login.net/) as my starting point and have my code talking to MySQL and creating sessions just fine.

I've gone through most every [SO question](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=php%20session%20ajax) regarding php sessions and ajax; but I still can't get my code to work how I want.

Now, I'm using ajax to call some other php scripts after the user successfully logs in, however it's not working properly.  In firefox, with all the cookies, history, etc cleared, it looks like the session variables aren't maintained with the ajax call.  However, if I [log-out](https://github.com/panique/php-login-minimal/blob/master/classes/Login.php#L105) and then log back in, the session variables seem to be passed properly across ajax.

For example:

In my logged_in.php script, I'm using ajax to call another script: view_samples.php.

**logged_in.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/loggedInButtons.js" > </script> <!-- all our ajax calls are here -->

<?php

    // debug some variables
    print_r($_SESSION);
    echo "<br>" . session_id() . "<br>";

    // if logged in
    if ($_SESSION['logged'] == 1) { 
    ?>
        <button class='btn btn-primary' id="view_samples"> View samples</button> <!-- calls view_samples.php -->
        <div id="ajaxResult"></div> <!-- results of ajax calls go here -->
    <?php
    } 

?>
```

**loggedInButtons.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#view_samples").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "view_samples.php",
            cache: false,
            success: function(result){
                $("#ajaxResult").html(result);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

**view_samples.php**

```
<?php
    session_start():

    // debug session
    print_r($_SESSION);
    echo "<br>" . session_id() . "<br>";

    if ($_SESSION['logged'] == 1) {
      // do something because we are properly logged in
    } else {
      echo "not logged in!";
    }

?>
```

When I log in with a browser that hasn't logged in before, I see it sets a session ID *X*; however when the button is pressed and the ajax call is made, I see a new session ID *Y*.  I then log-out and log back in and see that my session ID is *Y* (before ajax) and that my session ID is *Y* when I click the button (after ajax).

I've also noticed that if I keep logging-in & out without pressing the view samples button, a new session id generated each time.  However, as soon as I press the button, a whole new session id is created which seems to always be the one that is set if I log-out and then back in.

What am I missing?  What's the proper way to go about ensuring the first session that is created is maintained throughout ajax calls?  Should I POST the session id to the called script?

Comment: you need the  session_start(): in both php files, if not the $_SESSION will be empty, ajax will always keep your cookies all the way in and out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I solved things (as Freaktor's comment above didn't resolve the issue) - I'm manually passing the session ID through AJAX and then setting it in the new PHP script.  **I'm wondering if anyone could comment on the security of this** (as I'm not entirely sure how this all works)?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28041851/pass-sessionid-through-jquery-ajax-call-to-php#answer-28041927) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068791/how-to-get-set-session-id-or-should-it-be-generated-automatically#answer-7068971) post were helpful.

**logged_in.php**

```
<script>var session_id = '<?php echo session_id();?>';</script> <!-- store our session ID so that we can pass it through ajax -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/loggedInButtons.js" > </script> <!-- all our ajax calls are here -->

<?php

    // debug some variables
    echo "<br>" . session_id() . "<br>";

    // if logged in
    if ($_SESSION['logged'] == 1) { 
    ?>
        <button class='btn btn-primary' id="view_samples"> View samples</button> <!-- calls view_samples.php -->
        <div id="ajaxResult"></div> <!-- results of ajax calls go here -->
    <?php
    } 

?>
```

**loggedInButton.js**

```
var data = {func:'getData1',session_id:session_id}; // manually send the session ID through ajax
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#view_samples").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            url: "view_samples.php",
            success: function(result){
                $("#ajaxResult").html(result);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

**view_samples.php**

```
<?php
    session_id($_POST['session_id']); // get the session ID sent by AJAX and set it
    session_start():

    // debug session
    print_r($_SESSION);
    echo "<br>" . session_id() . "<br>";

    if ($_SESSION['logged'] == 1) {
      // do something because we are properly logged in
    } else {
      echo "not logged in!";
    }

?>
```

Comment: That is weird behavior unless the url of the AJAX page is not on the same domain as the main page. Might that be the case?